# multiple attachments in sendmail -UNIX

Tags: unix

I'm sending a mail with HTML and attachment, by sendmail in UNIX.
But Im unable to add mutliple attachment in this way, my goal is to send mail with html content andattachment - but unable to add multiple attchment here.

```
mail_msg2()
{

DIR="/home/input"
SENDING_FILE_NAME="ExportData.xls"

v_mailpart="$(uuidgen)/$(hostname)"
echo "From: hello@world.com 
To: hello@world.com 
Cc: hello@world.com 
Subject: $SubjectData
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$v_mailpart\"

MIME-Version: 1.0

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--$v_mailpart
Content-Type: text/html

$Body

--$v_mailpart
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/xlsx; name=$SENDING_FILE_NAME
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$SENDING_FILE_NAME

`base64 $DIR/$SENDING_FILE_NAME`

--$v_mailpart--" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t



}
```

Body=`cat $path/output/output.html`

Answer (score 0):

This bit:

```
--$v_mailpart
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: application/xlsx; name=$SENDING_FILE_NAME
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$SENDING_FILE_NAME

`base64 $DIR/$SENDING_FILE_NAME`
```

needs to be repeated for every attachment.